# Rename all .txt files in a directory and then open that file in perl

Tags: perl

I need some help with file manipulations and need some expert advice.

It looks like I am making a silly mistake somewhere but I can't catch it.

I have a directory that contains files with a `.txt` suffix, for example `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`.

I want to add a revision string, say `rev0`, to each of those files and then open the modified files. For instance `rev0_file1.txt`, `rev0_file2.txt`, `rev0_file3.txt`.

I can append `rev0`, but my program fails to open the files.

Here is the relevant portion of my code

```
my $dir   = "path to my directory";
my @::tmp = ();

opendir(my $DIR, "$dir") or die "Can't open directory, $!";
@::list = readdir($DIR);
@::list2 = sort grep(/^.*\.txt$/, @::list);
foreach (@::list2) {
  my $new_file = "$::REV0" . "_" . "$_";
  print "new file is $new_file\n";
  push(@::tmp, "$new_file\n");
}
closedir($DIR);

foreach my $cur_file (<@::tmp>) {
  $cur_file = $_;
  print "Current file name is $cur_file\n"; # This debug print shows nothing
  open($fh, '<', "$cur_file") or die "Can't open the file\n"; # Fails to open file;
}
```

Comment: You should describe what goes wrong and what errors you get. If you do not get any errors, add `use warnings` (which you already should be using). Also, why are you using the `::` syntax for your variables? Is this an attempt to circumvent `use strict`? Because if so, it is a very bad idea.

Comment: I'm surprised that `my @::tmp` isn't a syntax error

Comment: Are you sure `"$::REV0"` does what you want? Have you defined `$::REV0` somewhere?

Comment: @Borodin It looks like he's using `$::REV0` as a way of getting around defining variables with `my` or `our`. He can now claim he uses `use strict;` without actually having to use it.

Comment: @DavidW.: Yes, it's very unpleasant, but `$::REV0` would have to be defined as `'rev0'` beforehand for it to work, and I wonder if he's aware of that

Comment: @Borodin - of course, the big reason to `use strict;`. It picks up undeclared variables. But, in this case, `use strict;` does no good at all. The big problem is assigning `$cur_file = $_` when `$_` is undefined itself.

Comment: @DavidW.: I would be way too embarrassed to post code like that! Perhaps `user2812535` is just more blasé than me.

Comment: @Borodin This user is like 90% of the Perl programmers. They taught themselves bit-by-bit. They scrutinized obsolete code they found all over. They picked up old Perl books that have been left around. They fought their way into programming solutions by throwing everything they could at a problem until something worked. They read some _trick_ from some _expert_ (which is probably where the OP picked up `$::`). One of the *problems* with Perl is that it is so easy to *learn* that you can easily learn it the wrong way.

Comment: @Borodin - My son commented that most programming books (what's the technical term? ... Oh yeah!) suck. He said that the books he used to learn JavaScript, PHP, and other programming languages simply teach you the wrong way. For example, the basic PHP book doesn't cover object oriented design. The authors are more interested in getting you to produce code that can produce results than learning how to do things the right way.

Comment: @DavidW.: I agree with much of what you're saying. If you'd like to talk privately then please use 747u1x+th1sz8@sharklasers.com

Comment: @user2812535: As you have read, people like me who know Perl well can be very upset by such misuse of the language. I feel even worse for those who are maintaining Perl 5 to have it abused so dreadfully. Have you been taught to use `::identifier` by someone who should know better? If so, then please bring them before this court and have them comment on *why* they have told you to do such a horrible thing. You must ***never ever*** use that syntax, and it is inexcusable in any Perl code written this century

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach my $cur_file(<@::tmp>) {
    $cur_file = $_;
```

You are using the loop variable `$cur_file`, but you overwrite it with `$_`, which is not used at all in this loop. To fix this, just remove the second line.

Comment: This doesn't answer why the `open` fails.

Comment: @Zaid: Yes it does, because the code tries to open the file defined by `$cur_file`, which has been copied from `$_` - a leftover value from somewhere in the preceding code.

Comment: @Borodin : Regardless of the bug which TLP has identified, the file was never renamed. Atempting to open the renamed file is expected to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is the fact you are using `$cur_file` in your loop for the file name, but then reassign it with `$_` even though `$_` won't have a value at that point. Also, as Borodin pointed out, `$::REV0` was never defined.

You can use the `move` command from the `File::Copy` to move the files, and you can use `File::Find` to find the files you want to move:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use File::Copy;   # Provides the move command
use File::Find;   # Gives you a way to find the files you want

use constant {
    DIRECTORY  => '/path/to/directory',
    PREFIX     => 'rev0_',
};

my @files_to_rename;
find (
    sub {
       next unless /\.txt$/;   # Only interested in ".txt" files
       push @files_to_rename, $File::Find::name;
    }, DIRECTORY );

for my $file ( @files_to_rename ) {
    my $new_name = PREFIX . $file;
    move $file, $new_name;
    $file = $new_name;                              # Updates @files_to_rename with new name
    open my $file_fh, "<", $new_name;               # Open the file here?
    ...
    close $file_fh;

}

for my $file ( @files_to_rename ) {
    open my $file_fh, "<", $new_name;               # Or, open the file here?
    ...
    close $file_fh;
}
```

See how using Perl modules can make your task much easier? Perl comes with hundreds of pre-installed packages to handle zip files, tarballs, time, email, etc. You can find a list at the [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) page (make sure you select the version of Perl you're using!).

The `$file = $new_name` is actually changing the value of the file name right inside the `@files_to_rename` array. It's a little Perl trick. This way, your array refers to the file even through it has been renamed.

You have two choices where to open the file for reading: You can rename all of your files first, and then loop through once again to open each one, or you can open them after you rename them. I've shone both places.

Don't use `$::` at all. This is very bad form since it overrides `use strict;` -- that is if you're using `use strict` to begin with. The standard is not to use package variables (aka *global variables*) unless you have to. Instead, you should use *lexically scoped variables* (aka *local variables*) defined with `my`.

One of the advantages of the `my` variable, I really don't need the `close` command since the variable falls out of scope with each iteration of the loop and disappears entirely once the loop is complete. When the variable that contains the file handle *falls out of scope*, the file handle is automatically closed.

Comment: @user2812535: As David says, *"Don't use `$::` at all. This is very bad form "*

Comment: I'm not sure this helps much as the OP is clearly at sea with anything Perl. I am far from clear what his objective is, as *"Rename all .txt files in a directory and then open that file in perl"* isn't English, never mind definitive. Some contributors think he wants to copy each text file to one with the new name. Others think he just wants to rename each file and then open it. I believe it is the beginnings of a program that will modify the files while keeping a backup, and shouldn't be done this way at all. No one can help the OP until he tells us his intentions

Comment: I can't endorse your choice of `File::Find` when all the files are in the same directory. This is a case for `glob`

Comment: @Borodin I've recommended `glob` before, but found sometimes when someone says _"I have a directory that contains all the files"_, they sometimes mean the entire directory tree because they put the files under subdirectories under that directory. So, I simply just recommend `File::Find`. It works whether the user created a new directory and copied various files there. or if they created a whole new directory tree and scattered the files throughout.

Answer (score 0):

What you've attempted to store is the updated *name* of the file in `@::tmp`. The file hasn't been renamed, so it's little surprise that the code `die`d because it couldn't find the renamed file.

Since it's just renaming, consider the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy 'move';

for my $file ( glob( "file*.txt" ) ) {

    move( $file, "rev0_$file" )
      or die "Unable to rename '$file': $!";
}
```

---

From a command line/terminal, consider the `rename` utility if it is available:

```
$ rename file rev0_file file*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html), [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY script.  And [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) anytime you're doing file or directory processing.

There is no reason why you should be prefixing your variables with `::` so please simplify your code like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Copy;

my $dir = "path to my directory";

chdir($dir); # Make easier by removing the need to prefix path information

foreach my $file (glob('*.txt')) {
    my $newfile = 'rev0_'.$file;
    copy($file, $newfile) or die "Can't copy $file -> $newfile: $!";

    open my $fh, '<', $newfile;
    # File processing
}
```

Comment: `autodie` will handle all errors in `copy` that I can think of

Comment: My first iteration of this code didn't include the `or die`, but I added it after verifying the documentation in `autodie` didn't cover `copy`.  You made me double check though, and the following doesn't throw an error: `perl -Mautodie -MFile::Copy=copy -e 'copy qw(notreal.txt new_dest.txt)'`.  I think this is actually the preferred functionality, but had to think twice about it.

Comment: `autodie` won't cover `copy` directly because it is a function provided by `File::Copy` and not a built-in operator. I assume you mean that `notreal.txt` doesn't exist? And your `or die` version *does* throw an error in the same situation?  Then I need to find out why that is. I would expect the module's `sysopen` to fail because of the non-existent file, but there are multiple ways through the code depending on the platform

Comment: [`File::Copy #return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html#RETURN) states simply: `All functions return 1 on success, 0 on failure. $! will be set if an error was encountered.`

Comment: But the scope of `autodie` is lexical, so shouldn't the module's `sysopen`, `sysread` and `syswrite` fall under its scrutiny? Hmm, having tested it it seems not. My apologies: all this will seem obvious in the morning...

Comment: I actually find this encouraging.  I definitely advocate for the use of `autodie`, but I think it would be a bad design if it effected the file handling in imported modules.  The following should behave the same with or without the autodie module `perl -MFile::Slurp -Mautodie -e '$d = read_file("nothere.baz", err_mode => "quiet") // "nothing returned"; print $d, "\n";'`